# Make a list of equal length vectors

Tags: r

In a question here on SO ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661295/apply-a-function-over-groups-of-columns)) a poster asked a question and I gave an answer that works but there's a part that bugs me, creating a `list` from a vector to pass as a list of  indices.  So les say I have this vector:

```
n <- 1:10
#> n
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Let's say I want to break it up into a list of vectors and each vector is of length 3.  What's the best (shortest amount of code & or fastest) way to accomplish this?  We want to toss out item 10 since it there's a remainder of 1 (`10 %% 3`) from 10/3 (`length(n) - 10 %% 3`).

This is the desired outcome

```
list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9)
```

This will give us the indices of those that can't make a group of three:

```
(length(n) + 1 - 10 %% 3):length(n)
```

**EDIT**

Here's an interesting approach posted by Wojciech Sobala on the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661295/apply-a-function-over-groups-of-columns) this is linked to (I asked them to answer here and if they do I'll remove this edit)

```
n <- 100
l <- 3
n2 <- n - (n %% l)
split(1:n2, rep(1:n2, each=l, length=n2))
```

As a function:

```
indices <- function(n, l){
    if(n > l) stop("n needs to be smaller than or equal to l")
    n2 <- n - (n %% l)
    cat("numbers", (n + 1 - n %% l):n, "did not make an index of length", l)
    split(1:n2, rep(1:n2, each=l, length=n2))
}
```

Comment: All great answers but I think X,He's is the shortest code-wise.  Thanks, that was bugging me.  All much better approaches than what I was doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this does the job?

```
x = function(x, n){ 
    if(n > x) stop("n needs to be smaller than or equal to x")
    output = matrix(1:(x-x%%n), ncol=(x-x%%n)/n, byrow=FALSE)
    output
}
```

Edit: changed the output to a list

```
x = function(x, n){ 
    if(n > x) stop("n needs to be smaller than or equal to x")
    output = matrix(1:(x-x%%n), ncol=(x-x%%n)/n, byrow=TRUE)
    split(output, 1:nrow(output))
}

Example:
x(10, 3)
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 4 5 6

$`3`
[1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: It's not a list though so it won't work in that poster's question unless you wrap the `output` with `data.frame`

Comment: @TylerRinker: I changed the output to a list.

Answer (score 5):

```
xx <- 1:10
xxr <- rle(0:(length(1:10)-1) %/% 3)  # creates an rle object
fac3 <- rep( xxr$values[xxr$lengths == 3], each=3)  #selects the one of length 3
                                     # and recreates the shortened grouping vector
tapply(xx[ 1:length(fac3)],          # a shortened original vector
                       fac3, list)   # split into little lists
$`0`                                # Hope you don't mind having names on your list
[1] 1 2 3

$`1`
[1] 4 5 6

$`2`
[1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: I didn't actually edit your response just put my edit in the wrong place, apologies. +1

Answer (score 4):

It's not the shortest, but here's a little recursive version:

```
wrap <- function(n,x,lx,y) {
    if (lx < n) return (y)
    z <- x[-(1:n)]
    wrap(n, z, length(z), c(y, list(x[1:n])))
}

wrapit <- function(x,n) {
    wrap(n,x,length(x),list())
}

> wrapit(1:10,3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: Wow this one hurts my noodle. +1  I'm not even sure how it works (though indices are in reverse order)

Comment: To understand recursive functions, sometimes following the chain of function calls with paper and pencil can help. Or put a couple print statements in there to watch the list grow and the vector shrink.