# averaging every 16 columns in r

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apply a function over groups of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661295/apply-a-function-over-groups-of-columns)

I have a `data.frame` with 30 rows and many columns (1000+), but I need to average every 16 columns together. For example, the data frame will look like this (I truncate it to make it easier..):

```
Col1            Col2            Col3            Col4........

4.176           4.505           4.048           4.489
6.167           6.184           6.359           6.444
5.829           5.739           5.961           5.764
.
.
.
```

Therefore, I cannot aggregate (I do not have a list) and I tried:

```
a <- data.frame(rowMeans(my.df[,1:length(my.df)]) )
```

which gives me the average of the all 1000+ coumns, But is there any way to say I want to do that every 16 columns until the end? (they are multiple of 16 the total number of columns).

A secondary, less important point but would be useful to solve this as well.
The col names are in the following structure:

```
XXYY4ZZZ.txt
```

Once averaged the columns all I need is a new col name with only `XXYY` as the rest will be averaged out. I know I could use gsub but is there an optimal way to do the averaging and this operation in one go?

I am still relatively new to R and therefore I am not sure where and how to find the answer.

Comment: agreed @Joran, the answers to my question that you link to should be readily adaptable to answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example adapted from @ben's question and @TylerRinker's answer from [apply a function over groups of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661295/apply-a-function-over-groups-of-columns) .  It should be able to apply any function over a matrix or data frame by intervals of columns.

```
# Create sample data for reproducible example
n <- 1000
set.seed(1234)
x <- matrix(runif(30 * n), ncol = n)

# Function to apply 'fun' to object 'x' over every 'by' columns
# Alternatively, 'by' may be a vector of groups
byapply <- function(x, by, fun, ...)
{
    # Create index list
    if (length(by) == 1)
    {
        nc <- ncol(x)
        split.index <- rep(1:ceiling(nc / by), each = by, length.out = nc)
    } else # 'by' is a vector of groups
    {
        nc <- length(by)
        split.index <- by
    }
    index.list <- split(seq(from = 1, to = nc), split.index)

    # Pass index list to fun using sapply() and return object
    sapply(index.list, function(i)
            {
                do.call(fun, list(x[, i], ...))
            })
}

# Run function
y <- byapply(x, 16, rowMeans)

# Test to make sure it returns expected result
y.test <- rowMeans(x[, 17:32])
all.equal(y[, 2], y.test)
# TRUE
```

You can do other odd things with it.  For example, if you needed to know the total sum of every 10 columns, being sure to remove `NA`s if present:

```
y.sums <- byapply(x, 10, sum, na.rm = T)
y.sums[1]
# 146.7756 
sum(x[, 1:10], na.rm = T)
# 146.7756
```

Or find the standard deviations:

```
byapply(x, 10, apply, 1, sd)
```

**Update**

`by` can also be specified as a vector of groups:

```
byapply(x, rep(1:10, each = 10), rowMeans)
```

Comment: Hi jthetzel, thank you very much! this worked just fine. I thought that due to my basic R levels it would have take longer but actually it went very smooth...thank you again!

Comment: Thank you very much for the update!! these are all useful comments!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on a much smaller data frame:

```
rowMeans(my.df[,seq(1,length(my.df),by=16)])
```

Comment: you're taking the mean of only the columns in that sequence (1, 17, 33, etc.) rather than the mean of the group of columns 1:16, 17:32 etc.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am taking the mean of the columns 1:16 then from 17 to 32 and so on.
Bob and Ben and Joran, thank you for the answers! I will try different things and see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry.  Misread the question.

Comment: That is ok Bob, thank you for reading, I am sure I will be able to use your code in other situations.