# ddply with fixed number of rows

Tags: r, plyr

I want to break up my data by 'number of rows'. That is to say I want to send a fixed number of rows to my function and when I get to the end of the data frame (last chunk) I need to just send the chunk whether it has the fixed number of rows or less. Something like this:

```
ddply(df, .(8 rows), .fun=somefunction)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `plyr` you can add a category column:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))

somefunction <- function(df) {
    data.frame(mean(df$x), mean(df$y))
}

df$category <- rep(letters[1:10], each=10)

ddply(df, .(category), somefunction)
```

But, the apply family might be a better option in this case:

```
somefunction <- function(n, x, y) {
    data.frame(mean(x[n:(n+9)]), mean(y[n:n+9]))
}

lapply(seq(1, nrow(df), by=10), somefunction, x=df$x, y=df$y)
```

Answer (score 2):

If speed and brevity is of interest then for completeness (and using a chunk size of 4 rather than 8 to keep the example short) :

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(0)
DT = data.table(a=rnorm(10))
DT
                 a
 [1,]  1.262954285
 [2,] -0.326233361
 [3,]  1.329799263
 [4,]  1.272429321
 [5,]  0.414641434
 [6,] -1.539950042
 [7,] -0.928567035
 [8,] -0.294720447
 [9,] -0.005767173
[10,]  2.404653389

DT[,list(sum=sum(a),groupsize=.N),by=list(chunk=(0:(nrow(DT)-1))%/%4)]
     chunk       sum groupsize
[1,]     0  3.538950         4
[2,]     1 -2.348596         4
[3,]     2  2.398886         2
```

Admitedly, that's quite a long statement. It names the columns and returns the group size too to show you that the last chunk really does include just 2 rows as required, though.

Once comfortable it's doing the right thing, it can be shortened to this :

```
DT[,sum(a),by=list(chunk=(0:(nrow(DT)-1))%/%4)]
     chunk        V1
[1,]     0  3.538950
[2,]     1 -2.348596
[3,]     2  2.398886
```

Notice that you can do *on the fly* aggregations like that; they don't need to be added to the data first. If you have a lot of different aggregations in a production script, or just want to interact with the data from the command line, then very small productivity differences like this can sometimes help, depending on your workflow.

NB: I picked `sum` but that could be replaced with `somefunction(.SD)` or (more likely) just `list(exp1,exp2,...)` where each `exp` is any R expression that sees column names as variable names.

Comment: +1 some day I too will embrace the power that is `data.table`... some day

Answer (score 0):

You can define the 8 row ID within the call to `ddply`.

Not particularly elegant, but using `ddply` (and `head` for the example function)

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ddply(df, .(row_id = rep(seq(ceiling(nrow(df) / 8)), each = 8)[1:nrow(df)]),
             head, n = 1)
```