# R - Perform function for every two columns in data

Tags: r, maps, lapply

I have a dataframe with many (100+) pairs of coordinates

```
[lat1] [long2] [lat3] [long4] [..]  [..]
30.12    70.25    32.21    70.25  ..  ..
31.21    71.32    32.32    75.2   ..  ..
32.32    70.25    31.23    75.0   ..  ..
```

This function draws a line connecting the  coordinates in the first two columns of the dataframe

```
lines(mapproject(x=data$long2, y=data$lat1), col=3, pch=20, cex=.1)
```

I need to perform this function on every pair of lat/lon coordinates so that there is a new/unconnected line drawn for each one

Looking at this example 
 [Operate on every two columns in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107024/operate-on-every-two-columns-in-a-matrix) I think I need to create a list, how do I do that for each column pair?

Then, I can use lapply as described here https://nicercode.github.io/guides/repeating-things/ - how should I wrap my lines() call within a function?

Full script:

```
library(maps)
library(mapproj)

data <- read.csv("data.csv")

map('world', proj='orth', fill=TRUE, col="#f2f2f2", border=0, orient=c(90, 0, 0))

lines(mapproject(x=data$long, y=data$lat), col=3, pch=20, cex=.1)
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

With some help from the comments I've tried a method that performs sapply on every two columns, which seems to work as desired. This is open to improvements

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(0, 10, 20), 
                   Y2 = c(80, 85, 90), 
                   X3 = c(3, 10, 15), 
                   Y4 = c(93, 100, 105), 
                   X5 = c(16, 20, 35),
                   Y6 = c(100, 105, 130))


map('world', proj='orth', fill=TRUE, col="#f2f2f2", border=0, orient=c(90, 0, 0))

sapply(seq(1,5,by=2),function(i) lines(mapproject(x = (df[,i]), y = (df[,(i+1)])), col = 3))
```

Comment: You can reshape your data, and group the data then compute the function on all the groups

Comment: Can you include what you expect the reshaped data to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit works for me, but I would probably do it this way, because it generalizes better.

```
library(maps)
library(mapproj)

df <- data.frame(X1 = c(0, 10, 20), 
                 Y2 = c(80, 85, 90), 
                 X3 = c(3, 10, 15), 
                 Y4 = c(93, 100, 105), 
                 X5 = c(16, 20, 35),
                 Y6 = c(100, 105, 130))

draw_lines <- function(df){

#Make sure we get the order right for iterating over length
 x  <- sort(grep("X", names(df), value = TRUE), decreasing = FALSE)
 y  <- sort(grep("Y", names(df), value = TRUE), decreasing = FALSE)

#Check for vector lengths to be the same
stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))

#I dont want to print anything to console
invisible(lapply(1 : length(x), function(j){
         lines(mapproject(x = df[, x[j]], y = df[, y[j]]), col = 3, pch = 20, cex = .1)
         })
         )
}
```

And then:

```
map('world', proj='orth', fill=TRUE, col="#f2f2f2", border=0, orient=c(90, 0, 0))
draw_lines(df = df)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a good answer but I ran into an issue whereby I have unusable column names, i.e X1, Y2, X3, Y4....where X1 and Y2 are a match. What do you think of doing it this way?
sapply(seq(1,449,by=2),function(i) lines(mapproject(x = (df[,i]), y = (df[,(i+1)])), col = 3, pch = 20, cex = .1))

Comment: Should work here, when you can guarantee that your columns are sorted exactly how you need it. Are you sure that x = df[, i] and y = df[, i+1]. Just asking because you wrote in your question lines(mapproject(x=data$long2, y=data$lat1), col=3, pch=20, cex=.1). You should maybe edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

**REPLY TO UPDATED QUESTION**

This update to my original answer doesn't rely on any of the contents of the column names, but it does rely on the columns being ordered in `(latitude, longitude)` pairs. Since `?mapproject` indicates that it expects the coordinate pairs in the reverse order, I switch them in the function call.

I also don't assume a number of columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(maps)
library(mapproj)

lat_lons <- data.frame(lat1 = c(30, 31, 32), 
                       lon1 = c(70, 71, 70), 
                       lat2 = c(32, 32, 31), 
                       lon2 = c(70, 75, 75), 
                       lat3 = c(33, 33, 33),
                       lon3 = c(72, 73, 74))

ints <- seq(1, ncol(lat_lons) - 1)

map_lines <- function(int) {

  lines(mapproject(x = df[, int + 1], y = df[, int]), col = 3, pch = 20, cex = .1)

}

map('world', proj = 'orth', fill = TRUE, col = "#f2f2f2", border = 0, orient = c(90, 0, 0))

sapply(ints, map_lines)
```

**REPLY TO ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I think this does what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(maps)
library(mapproj)

lat_lons <- data.frame(lat1 = c(30, 31, 32), 
                       lon1 = c(70, 71, 70), 
                       lat2 = c(32, 32, 31), 
                       lon2 = c(70, 75, 75), 
                       lat3 = c(33, 33, 33),
                       lon3 = c(72, 73, 74))

ints <- names(lat_lons) %>% str_extract("[0-9]") %>% unique()

map_lines <- function(int) {

  df <- select(lat_lons, matches(int))
  lines(mapproject(x = df[, 2], y = df[, 1]), col = 3, pch = 20, cex = .1)

}

map('world', proj = 'orth', fill = TRUE, col = "#f2f2f2", border = 0, orient = c(90, 0, 0))

sapply(ints, map_lines)
```

First, get the unique set of integers from the data frame column names. Then, for each integer, apply a function that selects the 2 columns matching that integer and call `lines`.

The function `map_lines` doesn't return anything, but adds the lines to an active plot as a side effect. Not an ideal way to do things (I'd rather use `ggplot2` and assemble the pieces in a list before making the plot), but it works.

Comment: This is a good answer too, but I ran into an issue whereby I have unusable column names, i.e X1, Y2, X3, Y4....where X1 and Y2 are a match. What do you think of doing it this way?
sapply(seq(1,449,by=2),function(i) lines(mapproject(x = (df[,i]), y = (df[,(i+1)])), col = 3, pch = 20, cex = .1))

Comment: Sure! I updated my answer to remove assumptions about what the column names contain, while still not making an assumption about how many columns there are.